# xterm copying to CLIPBOARD using copy-selection causes automatic updating of CLIPBOARD upon mouse selection

Tags: linux, clipboard, xterm, gentoo

I've tried various ways to coerce xterm (versions 285 and 292) to copy the selection to the CLIPBOARD clipboard whenever I press Ctrl-Shift-C.  The most promising way thus far has been, in ~/.Xresources, to put this:

```
XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \
    Ctrl Shift <KeyPress> C:  copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Ctrl Shift <KeyPress> V:  insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

Ctrl-Shift-V works perfectly, but the copying has a nuance...

If I restart xterm, highlighting text puts things in the PRIMARY clipboard; this is expected, proper, default behavior.  If I hit Ctrl-Shift-C, it properly copies the current selection to CLIPBOARD clipboard.

The bug, however, is that if you highlight text after the first time you pressed Ctrl-Shift-C, you'll see that highlighting now copies to both PRIMARY *and* CLIPBOARD.  I cannot figure out how to stop xterm from updating CLIPBOARD upon selection... and it doesn't make sense to me that it would do it in the first place.

I said, at a specific point in time, to copy the selection to the clipboard... yet it just starts updating it automatically upon selection after doing it once...

Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Excellent question and interesting behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [Bug588785](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588785) interesting to read. A quick workaround would be to install and use xclipboard as seen in [Comment 145](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588785#145).

Answer (score -2):

I did it using React js, specially using a library called `updated-xterm-for-react` but is basically just an xterm wrapper that allows me to render this `XTerm` component so you should be able just to do it with your terminal.

Xterm docs doesn't specify when or where to call `getSelection` if they do I'm unaware, to do it, you basically need to call the `getSelection` method inside the function that you pass to the `onSelectionChange` method, and then copy it to clipboard, basically this:

Your handlers functions and event listener:

```js
   const handleCopy = () => {
    const selectedText = xtermRef.current.terminal.getSelection();
    if (selectedText) {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(selectedText)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Text copied to clipboard successfully!");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Unable to copy text to clipboard:", err);
            });
    }
  };

  const handlePaste = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then((clipboardText) => {
        if (clipboardText) {
            xtermRef.current.terminal.write(clipboardText);
            setCurrentInput((currentInput) => `${currentInput}${clipboardText}`);
            setPendingCommand((pendingCommand) => `${pendingCommand}${clipboardText}`);
        }
    });
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        console.log({ e })
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.code === 'KeyC') {
            handleCopy();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.code === 'KeyV') {
            handlePaste();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
}, []);
```

In your xterm component pass the function in the `handleSelection` method:

```js
<XTerm
        className="custom-terminal"
        ref={xtermRef}
        onData={handleData}
        onSelectionChange={handleSelection} // here
        focus={true}
        options={{
          cursorBlink: true,
          rendererType: "canvas",
          theme: {
            background: "#0f172a",
            foreground: "#65a30d",
            cursor: "#475569",
            selectionBackground: "yellow",
            selectionForeground: "black"
          },
          letterSpacing: 0,
          scrollback: 999999,
          fontFamily: "monospace",
          fontSize: 16
        }}
      />
```

This is going to be listening for the events and trigger on the keys, another thing you can do in your `handleData` function, listens for when data is equal to a Control + C (log it in the console to find it), and disallow it.

Comment: updated-xterm-for-react is a wrapper for xterm.js; this question is about a different program (the original xterm) in a different environment.